react native TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined
React native, having problems navigating to the next screen.
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, Dimensions, ImageBackground, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import { BASE_IMAGES } from '../../assets/BASE_IMAGES';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');


const SplashScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <ImageBackground source={BASE_IMAGES.laxLogoBlack} resizeMode={'cover'} style={styles.logo}>

          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SignInPage')}>
                <Text style={styles.btnText}>Continue</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },

  logo: {
    width: width,  
    height: height, 
  },


  btn: {
    backgroundColor: '#8A8A8A',
    paddingHorizontal: 90,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
    position: 'absolute',  
    bottom: 50,
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },

  btnText: {
    fontSize: 22,
    color: '#000000',
    textAlign: 'center',
  }

});

export default SplashScreen;

My AppNavigator page is
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import SplashScreen from '../screens/SplashScreen';
import SignInPage from '../screens/SignInPage';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const AppNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="SplashScreen">
        <Stack.Screen
          name="SplashScreen"
          component={SplashScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="SignInPage"
          component={SignInPage}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default AppNavigator;

I have installed npm install @react-navigation/native, npm install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context and npm install @react-navigation/native-stack but no matter what I keep getting the same error Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined. What am I doing wrong here?

There is workaround for this error. The navigator is not getting the route properly.
What you need to do is create a new class lets say Nav.js and add the following code
import * as React from 'react';

export const navigationRef = React.createRef();

export function navigate(name, params) {
  navigationRef.current?.navigate(name, params);
}

Now use this navigate method something like this in other files. In your case lets say
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, Dimensions, ImageBackground, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import { BASE_IMAGES } from '../../assets/BASE_IMAGES';
import {navigate} from './Nav.js'; 

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');


const SplashScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <ImageBackground source={BASE_IMAGES.laxLogoBlack} resizeMode={'cover'} style={styles.logo}>

          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn} onPress={() => navigate('SignInPage')}>
                <Text style={styles.btnText}>Continue</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  );
};

Hope this will solve your issue.

Thank you for your reply, I tried this it resolved the error but unfortunately now it won't navigate at all. Not sure why...
